# How to add a resizable, dragable overlay to a webpage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, userscripts

I'd like to make a userscript that can put an ***resizable***, ***dragable*** overlay over a browser game. Only I don't have a clue how to start.

It'd basically have to be a div with some styling and javascript applied to it, containing an `<iframe>`. I'd also like to pass a string displayed in the game screen (HTML5, not Flash) to the iFrame, but this can happen through the use of `$_POST` and `$_GET` parameters, as it probably wouldn't be possible otherwise due to some kind of "cross domain policy".

Can someone get me on my way, with an example of a basic Chrome userscript, that would allow me to inject some HTML code for the overlay div into the game?

Comment: Are you using Chrome exclusively? Not Tampermonkey and not Firefox?

Comment: @BrockAdams I'm using Chrome, but it needs to work with GreaseMonkey too.

Comment: @BrockAdams Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Yeah, that script works in Greasemonkey (which is a **Firefox** extension) or possibly in Tampermonkey.  So **you need to test the initial version in Firefox.** (Which is why I asked about Firefox above.  This question may be mis-tagged) ... The duplicate script needs some modification to run on Chrome (and possibly to work with a design flaw in Greasemonkey 1.0).  BUT, it shows the process for any browser.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something like an existing Javascript framework (gotta love em')?  I know this has been done [again](http://jqueryui.com/demos/) and [again](http://www.kendoui.com/web.aspx) and [again](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqDnR/) before.  I feel like doing this sort of Javascript yourself may not really be worth your time.  Usually when I see things like this, I offer the help of a framework.  Couldn't hurt to check one of them one, you may end up saving yourself a lot of time coding something that's been done before and tested through time.